# how to set date in linux to 30 seconds earlier using bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I'm trying to set the 'date' of in my linux box using shell script

currently I have

```
[root@localhost ~]# date_minus_30_sec=`date -d -30seconds`
[root@localhost ~]# echo $date_minus_30_sec
Wed Jul 16 10:13:26 PDT 2014
[root@localhost ~]# date -s=$date_minus_30_sec
date: extra operand ‘16’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

The error message is kind of cryptic.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do as the error message suggested "Try 'date --help' for more information."?  When doing so it stops at the bottom of the `date` man page showing examples of strings being quoted after an equal sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote it and remove the equal sign:

```
date -s "$date_minus_30_sec"
```

or use the full word:

```
date --set="$date_minus_30_sec"
```

Otherwise when you expand it you are passing in a lot of "extra parameters":

```
date -s Thu, Jul 16, 2015 13:24:26
```

Comment: found out that the '=' is the main problem.  this works date -s "$date_minus_30_sec"